# Javascript date calculation

Tags: javascript

I have date field,Onclick on date feild,i have to calculate the date with the current date .if entered date is one month older than today date.I have to popup amessage saying date is olderthan 1 month.

Date format is "yyyy-MM-dd".i want to compare with date "1984-03-20" to today date "2011-04-14".it should return number of months.

Any hints on this.
Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: Do you have an Date object of the enterade date or is just all String?

Comment: Felipe :I will get entered date as string in yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: Then you can do just do "new Date(theDateString)" to have an date object. And there's a lot of answers how to use the date object below.

Comment: @ Felipe:Not working with "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

Comment: really? tested on chrome and it worked. Maybe you could use regex then. Try something like this: var dateArray = dateString.split("-");  var date = new Date(dateArray[0],dateArray[1],dateArray[2])

Comment: @Felipe :entered date,i will parse as per your suggestion.What about todays date.How can i get year,month,date.From var t=new Date().

Comment: You can see the methods of Date class here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp (like getDate(), getMonth(), getFullYear())

Answer (score 3):

See this [discussion](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml) it has demos for getting date difference in javascript.
Also this is a good example: [javascript-date-difference-calculation](http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/) it shows how to get difference in month, in week or in year.

Comment: @user569125: you can make it to accept date in yyyy-MM-dd format.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help to you:

http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/javascript-date-comparison-t46552.html

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var days = 0;
var difference = 0;

Christmas = new Date("December 25, 2005");

today = new Date();

difference = Christmas - today;

days = Math.round(difference/(1000*60*60*24));

</script>
```

Comment: This does not take DST into account.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to compare dates in javascript is to first convert it to a Date object and then compare these date-objects.

Below you find an object with below function:

```
dates.inRange (d,start,end)

Returns a boolean or NaN:

    * true if d is between the start and end (inclusive)
    * false if d is before start or after end.
    * NaN if one or more of the dates are illegal.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = new Date('02 Jul 2009');
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() – 1);
```

You can read up about js Date object to see what formats it can accept.

[A blog about JS Date formats](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function checkdate (){

           var today = new Date()

           var dating = document.getElementById("date").attr("value");

           var new = new Date(dating);

           var diff = today - new;

           var days = Math.round(diff/(1000*60*60*24));

           if (days >= 30){

                alert("more than one month!");
           }
      }

    </script>

    <html><body>
       <input type="text" id="date" onClick="checkdate();"/>
    </html></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work. Pass the value of the field to dateString onclick and the code will determine whether the date is older than 1 month or not.

```
var dateString = '3/26/2011';
var selectDate = new Date(dateString); // convert string to date
var monthOld = new Date();

monthOld.setDate(monthOld.getDate() - 30); // subtract 30 days

if (selectDate < monthOld) {
    alert('older than one month');
}
else alert('ok');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cw4vb/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would advise you to adjust your requirement to 30 days. This is probably fine for your users and is unambiguous for both you and them. 1 month can be of varying length depending on the time of year.

for solution start with

```
var millisecond = 1;
var second = 1000;
var minute = second * 60;
var hour = minute * 60;
var day = hour * 24;
var week = day* 7;
```

then on date entry do this

```
if (usersDate < new Date().getTime() - 30 * day) {
   //Do popup / whatever
}
```

Alternatively if you really want to do month based interval then do

```
var now = new Date();
if (usersDate < now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1))) {
 //Do popup / whatever
}
```