# How to get calculate with dates in js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I've a datepicker, using jQuery. But I want to substract 5 days from the date that is selected with jQUery datapicker. How can I do this?

**--EDIT--**
This solved my problem:

```
date = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 5);
date = new Date(date);
$('#max_unsub_date').attr('value', date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664033/javascript-date-calculation

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your datepicker has an id of datePicker:

```
var pickedDate = $( "#datePicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
if ( pickedDate != null )
{
    pickedDate.setDate( pickedDate.getDate() - 5 );
}
```

Then if you wanted to send that back to the datepicker:

```
$( "#datePicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", pickedDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use datejs http://www.datejs.com/.

var date = (a date object created from your datepicker result);
date.add(-5).days();